# Linking static library into R

Tags: c++, r, static-libraries

I have a static library which I am trying to use inside my R package. This is only for internal use.

The libq.a for now is just within ./src folder. I was trying to add the following to src/Makevars:

```
PKG_LIBS="-l/path/to/lib/libq.a"
```

Where /path/to/lib is an absolute path to the libq.a location (for testing purposes only). But that doesn't seem to help. Do I have to do anything else in order to load that static library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work -- make sure you see the library used on the final link statement when the package is built.  Mind you, though, that -L is for the patch and -lq should be all.

Static libraries can also be added directly so try `/path/to/lib/libq.a` as is as an argument to `PKG_LIBS`.