# Rcpp: Install package with static libraries for platform independent usage

Tags: c++, r, static-libraries, rcpp, .a

I want to use the [libDAI C++](https://bitbucket.org/jorism/libdai) library within an R-package and want the package:

1. to be usable on Linux and Windows
2. save disc space (the external library has ~60 Mb)
3. the end user does not need to install boost and gmp for compilation

My current setup is:

- precompile libDAI

  - copy libdai.a to lib/
  - copy all  libDAI header files to inst/include
- add Makevar to src/

Modify Makevar file:

```
# include libraries
PKG_CPPFLAGS =-I../inst/include/
PKG_LIBS = -Llib -l../lib/libdai.a
```

My script for accessing the libDAI library is (test.cpp in src/):

```
#include <dai/factorgraph.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;
using namespace dai;

//'
//' Creates libDAI factor graph object
//'
//' @param factor_graph character definition of the factor graph
//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void initialize_factor_graph(const char* factor_graph) {

  // read the factor graph from the string
  std::istringstream fgStream(factor_graph);
  FactorGraph net;
  net.ReadFromString( fgStream );

  // Output some information about the factorgraph
  cout << "Factor graph has " << net.nrVars() << " variables" << endl;
  cout << "Factor graph has " << net.nrFactors() << " factors" << endl;

}
```

running `Rscript -e "Rcpp::compileAttributes('libdai')"`, followed by `R CMD INSTALL libdai` returns the error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'libdai' in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object 
'/home/jk/libs/R/libdai/libs/libdai.so':
  /home/jk/libs/R/libdai/libs/libdai.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN3dai11FactorGraphE
Error: loading failed
```

So my questions are:

- What is wrong with my setup?
- what is the best procedure to share my final package on CRAN?
- What is the nicest setup for sharing the package?

My question is closely related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781518/linking-static-library-into-r) and [this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-loadable-dll-with-minGW-compiled-linked-library-td3776733.html) question and several other post related to referencing static libraries, however I was not able to solve my problem with these links.

Comment: What should a user of `libdai` be able to do? Use some R functions that are backed by C++ code from libDAI? Write new C++ code that uses libDAI?

Comment: In very short, this is a _hard_ and open question.  When @coatless and I are both retired we will come back to this and write the paper about the (maybe five) different ways this can be tackled.  In short: it's not east, especially with an external library.  But a few CRAN packages do it: bundle the source, build a static library (which is an architecture-and-OS-dependent task) and then use it.

Comment: @RalfStubner I want to write C++ functions that use the inference and em algorithms provided by the C++ libDAI library. The end user will only use my R functions.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel thank you for your answer. However I should be able to somehow make use of libDAI? So it is not possible to pre-compile it, does this mean a user must set up gmb and boost and directly compile libDAI while compiling the R-package?

Comment: Assume eg CRAN has nothing (it may have libgmp though). You can get Boost _headers_ from BH.  If you need Boost linking it is much harder.  Forgetting these two, you will have to shop libDAI sources _and create build instructions_ for the three architectures so that your package can use it.  As I said: _hard_.

Comment: So as a first proxy, maybe delegate out to the libDAI website, assume someone has it built (on Linux or macOS, say) and write a simpler 'RcppDAI' package interfacing that.  You can share that via GitHub etc while you work out if/how to include libDAI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## How to link with a static library

You can either use `-L<directory> -l<name>` or `<path>`, i.e. in your case

```
PKG_LIBS = -L../lib -ldai
```

or

```
PKG_LIBS = ../lib/libdai.a
```

## Header placement

The headers for `libDAI` are only used internally. One cannot link to the functions declared in these headers. I would therefore not use `inst/include` for these headers.

## Dependencies on CRAN

The gmp library seems to be available on the CRAN builders, c.f. https://github.com/cran/gmp and https://cran.r-project.org/package=gmp. It seems that libDAI requires *linking* to boost (program options), c.f. https://bitbucket.org/jorism/libdai/src/83bd24a4c5bf17b0592a7b5b21e26bf052881833/Makefile.LINUX?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#Makefile.LINUX-49. However, looking at the actual `Makefile` it seems this is only used for tests and utility programs. So you might get away with the boost *headers* provided by the BH package.

## Pre-building static libraries

This is a common approach on Windows (c.f. https://github.com/rwinlib), but I find it unusual for Linux. The more common approach would be one of:

- include the sources in the package and compile during configure or package installation
- download the sources and compile during configure
- link with a system library (I haven't seen any for libDAI, though).

For all three approaches there are numerous examples on CRAN and GitHub. It is difficult to make a recommendation, though. I probably would go for "include the sources in the package" and use the Makefile provided by upstream as a starting point for building the library.

Comment: Pretty good answer. I would stress that 'Pre-building static libraries' is mostly about macOS and Windows. Some packages actually build their own static libraries:  both `nloptr` and `RcppRedis` either use an installed library _or_ build from source on demand if needed (respectively: `libnlopt` and `libhiredis`).  A few other packages just build the static library on demand.  That is probably the only route to take as `libDAI` is a wee bit obscure.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer it helped me a lot. I have a question related to your suggestion for the library dependencies. Does this mean, that the user should be able to compile my package without the need to compile `gmp` and `boost` on his system (Windows and Linux)?

Comment: @J.Kr For compilation the `gmp` library and header files will be necessary. Since these are available on CTAN, though, Windows and Mac Users will be able to get *pre-build* packages from there. For `boost` I expect that the headers provided by `BH` are sufficient for compiling the package.

Comment: @RalfStubner Thanks a lot for your help, I got the compilation running on Linux. However, the library requires gmpxx, It seems like this is not part of gmp. Additionally, I had a few other issues. I added an _Edit_ to my initial question.

Comment: @J.Kr At least on Debian et al. `gmpxx.h` is part of `libgmp-dev`. As for your other questions: It would be better to ask a new question for this, but be sure to (re)read the "extending Rcpp" vignette before hand. You can extend Rcpp without modifying third parts headers.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up.
A colleague of my also would like to used libdai as part of an R package. 
Is your package available somewhere? It would be very useful to us to see it in oder to get some inspiration. Thanks!

Comment: @DrYak Which package are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: If you aim is to do inference in Bayesian networks, there is an R package that directly does that for you: https://github.com/cbg-ethz/SGS.